# How do I show a dialog fragment over another app when sharing from that app?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm making an app which other apps share/send to. When this happens, I want to show a dialog over the top of the existing app, the user chooses one of the options, then my app does something invisible and the user pops back to the original app - much like when you share something to Google+ but have multiple accounts set up, and it lets you choose which account to use.

Currently the activity (`SendToActivity`) which is started on the SEND intent is essentially a normal activity, made invisible with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`. Am I going down the right path by using a `DialogFragment`, and changing `SendToActivity` to extend `FragmentActivity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using an AlertDialog, with an ArrayAdapter to make the list:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SendToActivity.this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        for(String[] player: players){
            adapter.add(player[0]);
        }
        builder.setTitle("Which Player?");
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                sendToPlayer(item);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
```